# how to get creation/deletion access of files present in usb via OTG in android studio?

Tags: android, android-permissions, java-io, android-file, usb-otg

I need to get creation/deletion access of files present in usb pendrive via OTG through android studio programatically, but according to my search, I think I need system root access for it.

Can someone provide idea how to get access without root access?

Thanking you in advance.